# Save mail we had read and load only new email in C#

Tags: c#, imap, pop3, email-client

I write a "email client" program to check and read mail.
I had download source-code of many author (in codeproject)but they program was loading very long and when i restart program must download it again.
I have idea to save mail we have downloaded and only download only new mail.
How can i save mail? I can use XML or SQL?
I using POP3 and IMAP.

Comment: What part of the saving troubles you? Have you problem choosing between XML files or an SQL database? Have you problem with how to create an XML file or save in an SQL database? How does your in memory representation look like? Do you have some fancy object model or just `byte[]`?

Comment: Save all content of mail. I have problem choosing between XML and SQl and create XML. Any Memory.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Limisoft library.

Here is the sample of code:

```
using LumiSoft.Net.IMAP;
using LumiSoft.Net.IMAP.Client;
using LumiSoft.Net;
```

...

```
using (IMAP_Client client = new IMAP_Client())
{
    client.Connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, true);
    client.Login("your.username@gmail.com", "your_cool_password");
    client.SelectFolder("INBOX");

    IMAP_SequenceSet sequence = new IMAP_SequenceSet();
    //sequence.Parse("*:1"); // from first to last

    IMAP_Client_FetchHandler fetchHandler = new IMAP_Client_FetchHandler();

    fetchHandler.NextMessage += new EventHandler(delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("next message");
    });

    fetchHandler.Envelope += new EventHandler<EventArgs<IMAP_Envelope>>(delegate(object s, EventArgs<IMAP_Envelope> e){
        IMAP_Envelope envelope = e.Value;
        if (envelope.From != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(envelope.Subject))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(envelope.Subject);
        }

    });

    // the best way to find unread emails is to perform server search

    int[] unseen_ids = client.Search(false, "UTF-8", "unseen");
    Console.WriteLine("unseen count: " + unseen_ids.Count().ToString());

    // now we need to initiate our sequence of messages to be fetched
    sequence.Parse(string.Join(",", unseen_ids));

    // fetch messages now
    client.Fetch(false, sequence, new IMAP_Fetch_DataItem[] { new IMAP_Fetch_DataItem_Envelope() }, fetchHandler);

    // uncomment this line to mark messages as read
    // client.StoreMessageFlags(false, sequence, IMAP_Flags_SetType.Add, IMAP_MessageFlags.Seen);
}
```

Bit complicated, but works fine. Limisoft library is not perfect, so be sure you test it well.

Comment: i tried this code and it worked as it is, however i am unable receive body. I added the new IMAP_Fetch_DateItem_Body() and added an event handler to fetchHandler.Body but in this function, i only see stream to null and BodySection to empty string. Any advise or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Messages on the server have a UID (at least for IMAP.)  [By definition](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html) the UID will only increase.  Meaning if you have a UID of 321, the next UID has to be 322 or higher.  So you could store the "Last UID" in your DB, and then get the highest UID from the server.  If it's higher than your last one, load the new ones.